# Include certain files with extention X only when in folders named Y: Ignore TypeScript generated JavaScript files in git

Tags: git, visual-studio, typescript, gitignore

I inherited code for a project in a zip file and my first step is to try to get it into a SCM system.  The code is developed in Visual Studio and utilizes NuGet and TypeScript.

The TypeScript compiler generates `*.js` and `*.js.map` files that I do not want to track.  As the project exclusively uses TypeScript I would like to generally exclude all `*.js` fies.

However, 3rd party JavaScript libraries that NuGet puts within folders called `Scripts` must still be included.

I tried the following in the repository's `.gitignore`

```sh
# Exclude JavaScript other than from NuGet packages
# This is a TypeScript project so JavaScript should not be used
*.js
*.js.map
!Scripts/*.js
```

This works in excluding all of the JavaScript files.  However, it does not include the JavaScript files in the Scripts folder.

Because TypeScript files are exist in many directories it is not desirable to enumerate all the directories in which to exclude the JavaScript files.

All the similar questions I have found have tended be in the context of ignoring all but accepted file extensions which is not what I am looking to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following seems to work as desired (git version 1.9.4.msysgit.0):

```
*.js
*.js.map
!**/Scripts/**/*.js
!**/Scripts/**/*.js.map
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include all subfolders using `**/*.js`

```
# Exclude JavaScript other than from NuGet packages
# This is a TypeScript project so JavaScript should not be used
*.js
*.js.map
!Scripts/**/*.js
```

PS: make sure you have latest git as it was only recently added.

Comment: Do you know how recently?  This is happening on Windows where the 2.x line is not available yet.  I kept thinking I would get around to finding a 2.0 build to work with, but haven't.  This does not seem to work on 1.9.4 msysgit on Windows.